# How to toggle between multiple text view automatically without button

Tags: swiftui

I want to automatically change text. I could have it working with a toggle button but I want to do it without button. I want it to keep alternating every 3 seconds.

Here's the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
   @State var homeString = true
   var body: some View {
       VStack {
            Text(homeString ? "Welcome." : "How can I help you?").font(.title)
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration:1.0))
          Button(action: {self.shortString.toggle()}) {
            Text("Toggle").padding()
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a timer to fire every 3 seconds and toggle the `homeString`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var homeString = true

    @State var timer: Cancellable?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(homeString ? "Welcome." : "How can I help you?")
                .font(.title)
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0))
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.timer = Timer.publish(every: 3, on: .main, in: .common)
                .autoconnect()
                .sink(receiveValue: { _ in self.homeString.toggle() })
        }
    }
}
```

If at any point you want to stop the timer just call:

```
timer?.cancel()
```